# How to prevent opening new tab or window while browsing in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

While browsing through iframe window I want to prevent any popups. Also when i click on link that wants to open new tab or window I want to get the url and put it into iframe.src. I found that there is a window.open method that opens the new tabs or windows but how to stop it and take the url?

Comment: Us the content of the Iframe coming from the same domain, or someone else's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override window.open with your own function:

```
var oldWindowOpen = window.open;
window.open = function (url, name, features, replace) {
  // handle window.open yourself
  myIframe.src = url;
  // if you want to use functionality of original window.open call the oldWindowOpen function
  oldWindowOpen(url, 'myName', 'myFeatures');
}
```

Just make sure this function is defined before anything that uses window.open