# how to avoid iframe to open in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to know how to avoid the iframe to open in new tab or new window by right click on the iframe and go for the option "This frame->show only this frame".

Or if they give same option like "This frame->show only this frame" this should show the page with same parent src. i want like, user to restrict to saw the iframe source alone.

Give some suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: [May be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419034/how-to-prevent-opening-new-tab-or-window-while-browsing-in-iframe)

Comment: IMHO I'd  highly discourage doing this, as this function exists for a reason.

Comment: I try to open Iframe of w3school in new tab, it shows the same page and we can't saw that particular frame alone.. how it possible, can you help me for that option atleast.?? @chade_

Comment: You can not....

Comment: @AlivetoDie window open has NOTHING to do with what OP is talking about.

Comment: @PadmaRubhan I have added the solution for your answer. Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you seriously want to disable it, add the below script to disable the right click for the entire page.

```
<script>
 document.oncontextmenu = document.body.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}
</script>
```

If you want to disable it for particular div (only for the iframe window). Please see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79k52rvu/4/)
here.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i used it already, it avoids only the right click. i want atleast, even though it open in new page it should redirect to index page or it open with parent page..